# "Identifier that starts with '.......' is too long"; sql exception thrown when insert value contains character ' (single quotes)?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a file upload function that throws sql exception

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near ','. 
The identifier that starts with   
'PGFzcDpHcmlkVmlldyBJRD0iR3JpZFZpZXcyIiANCiAgICAgICAgcnVuYXQ9InNlcnZlciI
gV2lkdGg9IjgyMHB4IiBBdXRvR2VuZXJhdGVTZWxlY3RCdXR0b249IlRy' is too long. 
Maximum length is 128"  whenever the file name contains a single quote character (')
```

File upload function below :

```
protected void btn_file_upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            byte[] byte_file = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
            string str_file = Convert.ToBase64String(byte_file);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into spt_files values('" + FileUpload1.FileName + "','" + str_file + "','" + dd_students.Text + "')", conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            lbl_file_upload.Text = "File uploaded!";
        }
        else
            lbl_file_upload.Text = "Choose a file";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And all your column types in `spt_files` table are character types? What are the value of your insert values?

Comment: You are storing image in database ,You can use LONGBLOB or BLOB data type in sql databse .

Comment: Your string may contain an @. To sql, it is a parameter to the sql command

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 protected void btn_file_upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            byte[] byte_file = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
            string str_file = Convert.ToBase64String(byte_file);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into spt_files values('" + FileUpload1.FileName.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + str_file + "','" + dd_students.Text + "')", conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            lbl_file_upload.Text = "File uploaded!";
        }
        else
            lbl_file_upload.Text = "Choose a file";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

And increase the size of column in table .

Comment: Thanks, but I am using parameterized query to get around it